# Create and set templates for custom taxonomies

Tags: custom-taxonomy, templates

I've created a custom taxonomy for a custom post type. Code:

```
add_action( 'init', 'register_taxonomy_mytaxonomies' );

function register_taxonomy_mytaxonomies() {

    $labels = array( 
        'name' => _x( 'MyTaxonomies', 'mytaxonomies' ),
        'singular_name' => _x( 'MyTaxonomy', 'mytaxonomies' ),
        'search_items' => _x( 'Search MyTaxonomies', 'mytaxonomies' ),
        'popular_items' => _x( 'Popular MyTaxonomies', 'mytaxonomies' ),
        'all_items' => _x( 'All MyTaxonomies', 'mytaxonomies' ),
        'parent_item' => _x( 'Parent MyTaxonomy', 'mytaxonomies' ),
        'parent_item_colon' => _x( 'Parent MyTaxonomy:', 'mytaxonomies' ),
        'edit_item' => _x( 'Edit MyTaxonomy', 'mytaxonomies' ),
        'update_item' => _x( 'Update MyTaxonomy', 'mytaxonomies' ),
        'add_new_item' => _x( 'Add New MyTaxonomy', 'mytaxonomies' ),
        'new_item_name' => _x( 'New MyTaxonomy', 'mytaxonomies' ),
        'separate_items_with_commas' => _x( 'Separate mytaxonomies with commas', 'mytaxonomies' ),
        'add_or_remove_items' => _x( 'Add or remove mytaxonomies', 'mytaxonomies' ),
        'choose_from_most_used' => _x( 'Choose from the most used mytaxonomies', 'mytaxonomies' ),
        'menu_name' => _x( 'MyTaxonomies', 'mytaxonomies' ),
    );

    $args = array( 
        'labels' => $labels,
        'public' => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus' => true,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'show_tagcloud' => true,
        'show_admin_column' => true,
        'hierarchical' => true,

        'rewrite' => true,
        'query_var' => true
    );

    register_taxonomy( 'mytaxonomies', array('MyCustomPostType'), $args );
}
```

Now I see a metabox on the right side of the custom post type in admin panel.
Then I've added 2 new **MyTaxonomies** : MyTax1 and MyTax2

Now I want to show

- my custom post type page in **Template1** in front end if the the admin selects MyTax1
- my custom post type page in **Template2** in front end if the the admin selects MyTax2

Like single.php

I am not looking for archive template.
I am trying to show something like **Page template** (like default feature in wordpress Page) - page atributes: where we see a dropdown menu that shows page templates we can select.

Or something like I would be able to select a template per/or for custom taxonomy in custom taxonomy edit page.

Answer (score 1):

Add new file called taxonomy- mytaxonomies.php and put you code . But so far I know to add like in page..it is not available in wp yet

Comment: thanks for that. I tried that before I asked the question. Anyhow if I create `taxonomy-mytaxonomies.php` it will work as `mytaxonomies` 's archive. Won't it??
I mean we can list all the custom posts those categorized / classified as `mytaxonomies` in that page. Am I right??

Comment: yes, exactly what you say, upvote is appreciated

Comment: ok.. thanks.. I am unable upvote you because of my reputation is just 6. minumum 15 reputation is needed for upvote. I'll ask my friend to upvote u shortly..

Comment: ok, you can mark as accepted answer

Comment: upvoted. But I can't accept the answer because this is not the exact solution for the question. thanks for your time. much appereciated..